# Check if Kubernetes deployment is updated

Tags: kubernetes

I am performing image update for my 2 services. But during update I want to run first service only when second service has been fully upgraded. For this, I am using `initContainers`, is it correct to compare ready and updated field of deployment status object like this,

`$output = kubectl get deployment second-service -o jsonpath="{.status['replicas', 'updatedReplicas']}"; $arr = $output.Split(" "); $arr[0] -eq $arr[1]`;

I tried using `kubectl wait`, but in my experience it has inconsistent behaviour

P.S: I have had bad experience with `kubectl rollout status` as well. Second service is a stateless service and doesn't expose any APIs/health-probes, seeking suggestions for setting up readiness probes if that's an option

Comment: You should hopefully design your services not to have such tight coupling

Comment: first service enqueue a job, second service picks up the job. In my scenario updated first service enqueue a job, but older second service picks it immediately. Any suggestions, how to tackle this?

Comment: use versioning - like your old service couldn't handle a version 2 of the task, etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can compare when the **ready** and **updatedReplicas** fields are equal, it means that all pods have been updated and are ready to serve traffic.

**Try Rolling updates which may help to resolve your issue** :

Readiness probes allow the deployment to gradually update pods while giving you the control to determine when the rolling update can proceed. Deployments implement the concept of ready pods to aid rolling updates.

Before setting up rolling updates, set both services [readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) in place. These probes check if a pod is healthy and prepared to handle traffic on a regular basis. You can start the first service's update once the second service deployment is complete and its pods are indicated as ready by their probes.

You can also use [kubectl rollout pause/resume](https://Readiness%20probes%20allow%20the%20deployment%20to%20gradually%20update%20pods%20while%20giving%20you%20the%20control%20%20to%20determine%20when%20the%20rolling%20update%20can%20proceed.%20Deployments%20implement%20the%20concept%20of%20%20ready%20pods%20to%20aid%20rolling%20updates.%20%20Before%20setting%20up%20rolling%20updates,%20set%20both%20services%20readiness%20probes%20in%20place.%20These%20probes%20%20check%20if%20a%20pod%20is%20healthy%20and%20prepared%20to%20handle%20traffic%20on%20a%20regular%20basis.%20You%20can%20start%20the%20%20first%20service%27s%20update%20once%20the%20second%20service%20deployment%20is%20complete%20and%20its%20pods%20are%20%20indicated%20as%20ready%20by%20their%20probes.%20%20%20%20You%20can%20also%20use%20kubectl%20rollout%20pause/resume%20to%20manage%20deployments%20during%20consecutive%20%20updates.%20Consider%20tools%20like%20Argo%20rollouts,%20which%20provide%20advanced%20functionalities%20for%20handling%20%20complex%20rollouts%20and%20deployments,%20which%20are%20capable%20of%20managing%20rollouts%20across%20several%20%20services,%20dependencies,%20and%20pre%20and%20post%20rollout%20activities.%20%20%20%20Also%20refer%20to%20Jeff%20Geerling%20blog%20on%20updating%20a%20Kubernetes%20Deployment%20and%20waiting%20for%20it%20to%20roll%20%20out%20in%20a%20shell%20script,%20which%20may%20help%20to%20resolve%20your%20issue.%20%20%20%20%20Comment%20:%20As%20per%20this%20official%20Pod%20readiness,%20Set%20up%20rolling%20updates%20with%20readiness%20gates%20for%20%20both%20services.%20These%20gates%20guarantee%20that%20a%20predetermined%20number%20of%20pods%20are%20prepared%20%20before%20the%20rollout%20continues.%20Assign%20the%20first%20service%27s%20readiness%20gate%20value%20to%20be%20dependent%20on%20%20the%20successful%20upgrade%20of%20the%20second%20service.%20Annotations%20or%20labels%20on%20the%20pod%20templates%20can%20%20do%20this.%20The%20first%20service%20update%20will%20be%20automatically%20paused%20by%20Kubernetes%20until%20the%20second%20%20service%20satisfies%20the%20readiness%20gate%20requirements.) to manage deployments during consecutive updates. Consider tools like [Argo rollouts](https://argo-rollouts.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which provide advanced functionalities for handling complex rollouts and deployments, which are capable of managing rollouts across several services, dependencies, and pre and post rollout activities.

Also refer to Jeff Geerling [blog](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/updating-kubernetes-deployment-and-waiting-it-roll-out-shell-script) on updating a Kubernetes Deployment and waiting for it to roll out in a shell script, which may help to resolve your issue.

**Edit1:**

Apart from the above mentioned official doc on **Configuring Readiness probes**, You can also refer to this Dev [Tutorial](https://dev.to/pavanbelagatti/configure-kubernetes-readiness-and-liveness-probes-tutorial-478p) by Pavan Belagatti on how to Configure Kubernetes Readiness and Liveness Probes for more information.